# Looping through ruby hashes

Tags: ruby

I am trying to follow [this example](https://sethvargo.com/unit-testing-chef-cookbooks/), however when I can't find a way to loop through the hash as he does:

```
...  
platforms = {
  'MyOS' => {
    'package' => 'package',
    'versions' => ['1.0', '2.0','3.0']
  }
}
...
platforms.each do |platform, (package, versions)|
  versions.each do |version|
    context "On #{platform} #{version}" do
    before do
      Fauxhai.mock(platform: platform, version: version)
    end

    let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::ChefRunner.new.converge('cookbook::recipe') }

    it "Installs the package" do
      chef_run.should install_package package
    end
  end
end
...
```

I get the following error:

```
/path/file.rb:XX:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

For some reason the `|a, (b,c)|` is not working, the round brackets are ignored.

Seems like `platform` contains (as expected) *'MyOS'*, however the iterator `package` equals *'{"package"=>"package", "versions"=>["1.0", "2.0", "3.0"]}'* and `versions` is empty.

I am expecting the following:

```
platform = "MyOS"
package = "package"
versions = ["1.0", "2.0", "3.0"]
```

So I am able to access the package name while looping through the versions of the platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Every platform has a name and a set of attributes. Every attribute has a name and a value.

```
platforms.each do |name, platform|
  puts "platform = #{name}"
  platform.each do |attribute, value|
    puts "#{attribute} = #{value}"
  end
end
```

Comment: This is close to what I need, however I need to be able to access the package name on each version in the list.
Looping this way I only can have access to the package name on the first iteration, and I don't think it is appropriate to store this value on an external variable.

Comment: I wanted to reproduce what you provide as output needed. If it's something differente please update the question and I'll change my answer.

Comment: In my example you have versions in `platform['versions']`

Comment: That is just what I was looking for, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: My pleasure Sir :) I didn't realize you wanted that.

Answer (score 1):

If we have

```
platforms = { 'MyOS' => { 'package'=>'package', 'versions' => ['1.0', '2.0','3.0'] } }
```

and

```
platforms.each do |platform, (package, versions)|...
```

the first (and only) element (key-value pair) of `platforms` that is passed to the block is

```
platforms.first
  #=> ["MyOS", {"package"=>"package", "versions"=>["1.0", "2.0", "3.0"]}]
```

You are assigning the block variables to this value:

```
platform, (package, versions) = ["MyOS", {"package"=>"package",
  "versions"=>["1.0", "2.0", "3.0"]}]
```

By *parallel assignment* (sometimes called *multiple assignment*), Ruby obtains:

```
platform          #=> "MyOS" 
package, version  #=> {"package"=>"package", "versions"=>["1.0", "2.0", "3.0"]}
```

Then by applying parallel assignment once again, she obtains:

```
package           #=> {"package"=>"package", "versions"=>["1.0", "2.0", "3.0"]}
versions          #=> nil
```

which is not what you want. Nor should this result be surprising, considering that `platform.first` only contains two elements. Instead you want two block variables, `platform, h` so that

```
platform, h = ["MyOS", {"package"=>"package", "versions"=>["1.0", "2.0", "3.0"]}]
platform #=> "MyOS" 
h #=> {"package"=>"package", "versions"=>["1.0", "2.0", "3.0"]}
```

then within the block you will need to manipulate the hash `h`.